Microsoft Graph Java SDK invalidate refresh token or user session is not working
I am looking to invalidate or revoke refresh tokens when a User sign out. I would also like to invalidate access tokens provided from Microsoft, but that don't seem to be possible. From what I have read and looked into with Microsoft Graph using Java, there are currently two approaches that I can try.
Microsoft Graph Rest API v1.0
user: revokeSignInSessions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http 

implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:6.19.0'

graphServiceClient.users().byUserId(azureUserId).revokeSignInSessions().post()

Microsoft Graph Rest API beta
user: invalidateAllRefreshTokens 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-invalidateallrefreshtokens?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http implementation 

'com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph-beta:6.21.0' 

graphServiceClient.users().byUserId(azureUserId).invalidateAllRefreshTokens().post()

How I have tested for both v1 and beta APIs:

1. I used the specific libraries depending on which api. 
Set up the implementation that calls the api using graph
2. I created a public endpoint that takes in the Object ID to pass to the api to revoke the User's tokens for testing
3. I login using my Sign In Policy to get a code
4. I get the Code to trade in for an access token
5. I hit my public endpoint to request Microsoft Graph Service to invalidate my signed in User by Object ID using Postman
6. I waited 5, 10, 15 and 30 minutes plus
7. I make a request for a new access token token using the refresh token belonging to my User by Object ID using Postman
8. I was able to request a new access token when I was expecting to be rejected.

After trying different approaches and waiting different amount of time, I was still able to request and get a branch new access token with my refresh token that was supposed to no longer be valid.

Here is the Audit log of the User

Where did I blunder?

What's the response when you call revokeSignInSessions? Does it reset user's property signInSessionsValidFromDateTime?

I get a true boolean response. I can't see the signInSessionsValidFromDateTime value, how do I check that?

You need to specify signInSessionsValidFromDateTime in select query option. The property is not returned by default

I do see the signInSessionsValidFromDateTime now after selecting for the value from the User. But when I try to update the value, an error occurs. I will try to share what I did but it is harder to show here. ***graphUser.setSignInSessionsValidFromDateTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
return graphServiceClient.users().byUserId(azureId).patch(graphUser); *** ODataError: The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set

I may have misunderstood what you meant, but I was able to retrieve the value for signInSessionsValidFromDateTime from the User. I made a request to revokeSignInSessions for the User and then requested the User's signInSessionsValidFromDateTime attribute. It showed that the value was indeed set to expire, "signInSessionsValidFromDateTime": "2024-11-04T13:55:34Z", but I was still able to request for an access token via refresh token minutes later.

Here is a more direct message when I tried to directly update the attribute: "detail": "Property 'signInSessionsValidFromDateTime' is read-only and cannot be set."
